# I have the refresh token stored, How can I use it for refreshing my access token

Tags: python, google-drive-api

As per my reading, I can see curl to get the access_token using my refresh token. How can i reuse my refresh token using python.
Thanks and sorry if this is a kind of any duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Google APIs Python Client Library, the refresh token will be used automatically when your access token expires. The OAuth2Credentials object has a `refresh()` method for doing this manually. More information here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#OAuth2Credentials

Comment: Thanks Eric for the pointer. Another thing that pops up in my mind is that in this case then, What I can do is to store the credential object in my database using cPickle and then use it to authorize when in need after retreiving from database. Please point me if I m right or wrong.

Comment: If you scroll down on the page you can see the storage options that the library has for credentials.

Comment: Hey Eric, I just did a bit of homework on the refresh token as you indicated.Thou google refreshes the token automatically , I want to store the refresh token and use it to get the token whenever required in future. So I am thinking of storing the refresh token and then use it to retrieve the access token whenever user logs in and then query the drive api. Now my problem, it doing this, I need to revoke the token when it gets expired. Reading the doc gets me the idea that refresh token lives for around 6 months. When to revoke is the question.

Comment: refresh token lives forever, until the *user* revokes it.